# How do you declare a shared std_logic_vector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am currently trying to make a shared array declaration in my architecture but it isn't working and it keeps giving me a syntax error, can someone explain to me why this is so?

```
architecture behav of mpy8 is
shared variable P : std_logic_vector (17 downto 0); // doesn't work
```

I want to use the variable P in my transition process and asserted outputs process.

Comment: does it work if you make it a shared signal?

Comment: I haven't tried using shared signal, but is there a difference?

Comment: from my basic understanding, signals are used at top level of an architecture, variables are for within a process

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I keep getting "Syntax error"

Comment: it seems like that a shared variable has to be declared within a process

Comment: It's likely a valid declaration.  There appears to be something else not visible in your code snippet.  Note // is not a comment delimiter in VHDL.

Comment: What tool chain and VHDL version do you use? Shared variables must be declared as protected types since VHDL 2008. Before VHDL 2008 this keyword is unknown. STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is not a protected type.

Comment: I'm using design works 5 and what do u mean by protected?

Comment: There isn't any such thing as a "shared signal". Signals are already generally visible to to the entire architecture.

Comment: @BeginnerC. Protected types are the replacement for the original VHDL-93 shared variables, first introduced with VHDL-2002. They provide guaranteed atomic access to the shared state to prevent race conditions with multiple processes altering the shared variable at the same time. From 2002-on shared variables can only be instances of a protected type.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to add the actual error message to the question, and the VHDL language version. There is currently a lot of speculation going on.

Answer (score 0):

variables are usable only within one process in vhdl. You don't allowed to use variable within architecture block outside process. In order to share values between different process or entities you need several signal. All process can read one signal. But only one process is allowed to write in the same signal.

perhaps the example below can help you. It is data memory for processor i wrote in my last semester:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use work.Instructions_pack.all;


    entity DataMemory is

        generic(
            size : natural := 8 --number of instructions
        );  
        port(
            clk_i           : in  std_logic;
            rst_i           : in  std_logic;
            alu_result_i    : in  std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
            writeData_i     : in  std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
            memWrite_i      : in  std_logic;   
            memRead_i       : in  std_logic;
            loadMode_i  : in  load_mode;
            storeMode_i : in store_mode;

            readData_o   : out std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    end entity DataMemory;

    architecture behaviour of DataMemory is
        constant size2 : integer := size * 4;
        type dataMemType is array (0 to size2 - 1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal dataMem : dataMemType := (
                "11111011","00000000","00000000","00000000",
                "11101111","01000010","00000000","00000000",
                "00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000",
                "00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000",
                "00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000",
                "00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000",
                "00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000",
                "00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000"
        );
        signal readout : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        signal loadWordRaw : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        signal loadHalfRaw : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        signal loadByteRaw : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        signal loadHalfSigned : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        signal loadByteSigned : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

        begin

        --determines how much bytes are loaded
        loadWordRaw <= dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i))) &
                    dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 1) &
                    dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 2) &
                    dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 3)     when memRead_i = '1' and loadMode_i = ld_lw ELSE
                    (others => '-');
        loadHalfRaw <= ("00000000" & "00000000" & 
                    dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i))) &
                    dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 1))    when (memRead_i = '1') and ((loadMode_i = ld_lh) or (loadMode_i = ld_lhu)) ELSE
                    (others => '-');
        loadByteRaw <= "00000000" & "00000000" & "00000000" & 
                    dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)))         when memRead_i = '1' and ((loadMode_i = ld_lb) or (loadMode_i = ld_lbu)) ELSE
                    (others => '-');

        --signed: resize to 32 bit
        loadHalfSigned <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(loadHalfRaw(15 downto 0)), 32)) when loadMode_i = ld_lh ELSE
                    (others => '-');
        loadByteSigned <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(loadByteRaw(7 downto 0)), 32))  when loadMode_i = ld_lb ELSE
                    (others => '-');

        --which mode is chosen
        readout <=  loadWordRaw         when loadMode_i = ld_lw ELSE
                    loadHalfRaw         when loadMode_i = ld_lhu ELSE
                    loadHalfSigned  when loadMode_i = ld_lh ELSE
                    loadByteRaw         when loadMode_i = ld_lbu ELSE
                    loadByteSigned; 

        dataMem_process : process(clk_i, rst_i) is
        begin
            if rst_i = '1' then
                readData_o <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge(clk_i) then
                readData_o <= readout;
                if memWrite_i = '1' then
                    if storeMode_i = st_sw then --store normal
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i))) <= writeData_i(31 DOWNTO 24);
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 1) <= writeData_i(23 DOWNTO 16);
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 2) <= writeData_i(15 DOWNTO 8);
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 3) <= writeData_i(7 DOWNTO 0);
                    elsif storeMode_i = st_sh then      --store half
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i))) <= writeData_i(15 DOWNTO 8);
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i)) + 1) <= writeData_i(7 DOWNTO 0);
                    else    --store byte
                        dataMem(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(alu_result_i))) <= writeData_i(7 DOWNTO 0);
                        end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process dataMem_process;                

    end architecture;
```

Package "Instructions_pack":

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    package Instructions_pack is
        constant c_op_bits      : integer                      := 6;
        constant c_instr_bits   : integer                      := 5;
        constant c_immed_bits   : integer                      := 16;
        constant c_address_bits : integer                      := 26;
        ----------------------------------------------------
        --- MIPS registers ---------------------------------
        ----------------------------------------------------
        constant R0             : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        constant Rat            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"1";
        constant Rv0            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"2";
        constant Rv1            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"3";
        constant Ra0            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"4";
        constant Ra1            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"5";
        constant Ra2            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"6";
        constant Ra3            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"7";
        constant Rt0            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"8";
        constant Rt1            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"9";
        constant Rt2            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"A";
        constant Rt3            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"B";
        constant Rt4            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"C";
        constant Rt5            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"D";
        constant Rt6            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"E";
        constant Rt7            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '0' & x"F"; --15
        constant Rt8            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"8"; --24
        constant Rt9            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"9"; --25
        constant Rs0            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"0"; --16
        constant Rs1            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"1"; --17
        constant Rs2            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"2"; --18
        constant Rs3            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"3"; --19
        constant Rs4            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"4"; --20
        constant Rs5            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"5"; --21
        constant Rs6            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"6"; --22
        constant Rs7            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"7"; --23
        constant Rk0            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"A"; --26
        constant Rk1            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"B"; --27
        constant Rgp            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"C"; --28
        constant Rsp            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"D"; --29
        constant Rfp            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"E"; --30
        constant Rra            : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := '1' & x"F"; --31

        ----------------------------------------------------
        ------- r type constants ---------------------------
        ---------------------------------------------------- 
        type R_Type_Constant is record
            opcode : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
            funct  : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
        end record;
        --reg <= c_add.opcode & rs & rt & rd & shamt & c_add.funct;
        constant c_add : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"0"
        );
        constant c_addu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"1"
        );
        constant c_and : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "000000",
            funct  => "10" & x"4"
        );
        -- count leading ones
        constant c_clo : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => "10" & x"1"
        );
        -- count leading zeros
        constant c_clz : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => "10" & x"0"
        );
        constant c_div : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "01" & x"A"
        );
        constant c_divu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "01" & x"B"
        );
        --multiply
        constant c_mult : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "01" & x"8"
        );
        --unsigned multiply
        constant c_multu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "01" & x"9"
        );
        --multiply without overflow
        constant c_mul : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => "00" & x"2"
        );
        --multiply and add
        constant c_madd : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => (others => '0')
        );
        --unsigned multiply add
        constant c_maddu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => "00" & x"1"
        );
        --multiply subtract
        constant c_msub : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => "00" & x"4"
        );
        --unsigned multiply subtract
        constant c_msubu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => "01" & x"C",
            funct  => "00" & x"5"
        );

        constant c_nor : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"7"
        );

        constant c_or : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"5"
        );
        --logical shift left
        constant c_sll : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => (others => '0')
        );
        --shift left logical variable
        constant c_sllv : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "00" & x"4"
        );
        --shift right arithmetic
        constant c_sra : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "00" & x"3"
        );
        --shift right arithmetic variable
        constant c_srav : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "00" & x"7"
        );
        --shift right logical
        constant c_srl : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "00" & x"2"
        );
        --shift right logical variable
        constant c_srlv : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "00" & x"6"
        );
        --subtract with overflow
        constant c_sub : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"2"
        );
        --subtract without overflow
        constant c_subu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"3"
        );

        constant c_xor : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"6"
        );
        --comparison instructions
        --set less than
        constant c_slt : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"A"
        );
        --set less than unsigned
        constant c_sltu : R_Type_Constant := (
            opcode => (others => '0'), funct => "10" & x"B"
        );

        ------------------------------------------------------
        ----Branch constants
        ------------------------------------------------------
        type Branch_Type_Const is record
            opcode : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rt     : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        end record;

        type Branch_Type_2regs_Const is record
            opcode : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
        end record;

        --branch on equal, use 2 registers
        constant c_beq : Branch_Type_2regs_Const := (opcode => "00" & x"4");

        --branch on not equal, use 2 registers
        constant c_bne : Branch_Type_2regs_Const := (opcode => "00" & x"5");

        -- branch on greater than equal zero
        constant c_bgez : Branch_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"1",
            rt     => "0" & x"1"
        );

        --branch on greater than equal zero and link 
        --(save the address of next instruct. in reg. 31)
        constant c_bgezal : Branch_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"1",
            rt     => "1" & x"1"
        );

        --branch on greater than zero
        constant c_bgtz : Branch_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"7",
            rt     => (others => '0')
        );

        --branch on less than equal zero
        constant c_blez : Branch_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"6",
            rt     => (others => '0')
        );

        --branch on less than zero and link
        --(save address in reg. 31)
        constant c_bltzal : Branch_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"1",
            rt     => "1" & x"0"
        );

        --branch on less than zero
        constant c_bltz : Branch_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"1",
            rt     => (others => '0')
        );

        ------------------------------------------------------
        -----i type instructions, load store
        ------------------------------------------------------
        subtype OP_Type_Const is std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);

        constant c_addi  : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"8";
        constant c_addiu : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"9";
        constant c_andi  : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"C";
        constant c_ori   : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"D"; --immediate or
        constant c_xori  : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"E";
        --constant manipulation: load upper immediate
        constant c_lui   : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"F";
        --set less than
        constant c_slti  : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"A";
        constant c_sltiu : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"B";
        --load instructions
        --load byte
        constant c_lb    : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"0";
        --load unsigned byte
        constant c_lbu   : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"4";
        --load halfword
        constant c_lh    : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"1";
        --load halfword unsigned
        constant c_lhu   : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"5";
        --load word
        constant c_lw    : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"3";
        --lw left
        constant c_lwl   : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"2";
        --lw right
        constant c_lwr   : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"6";
        --load linked
        constant c_ll    : OP_Type_Const := "11" & x"0";
        --store word (sw)
        constant c_sw    : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"B";
        --store byte
        constant c_sb    : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"8";
        --store halfword
        constant c_sh    : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"9";
        --store word left
        constant c_swl   : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"A";
        --store word right
        constant c_swr   : OP_Type_Const := "10" & x"E";
        --store conditional: olways succeeds on SPIM (stores 1 to rt)
        constant c_sc    : OP_Type_Const := "11" & x"8";

        ------------------------------------------------------
        --Jump Instructions
        ------------------------------------------------------
        type J_Type_Const is record
            opcode : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rt     : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            funct  : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
        end record;

        --jump unconditionally to instruction at target
        -- PC(31 downto 28) & target(26 downto 0) & "00"
        constant c_j : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"2";

        --Jump and link: unconditionally jump to instruction
        --at target address, save the address of next
        --instruction in register $ra (register 31)
        --PC(31 downto 28) & target(26 downto 0) & "00"
        constant c_jal : OP_Type_Const := "00" & x"3";

        --jump and link register:
        --unconditionally jump to instruction whose address
        --is in register rs. Save address of next instruct.
        --in register rd (default reg $ra)
        constant c_jalr : J_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "00" & x"0",
            rt     => "00000",
            funct  => "00" & x"9"
        );

        --jump register:
        --unconditionally jump to instruction whose address is in register rs
        constant c_jr : J_Type_Const := (
            opcode => "000000",
            rt     => "00000",
            funct  => "00" & x"8"
        );

        ------------------------------------------------------

        --type for r type instructions
        type R_Type is record
            opcode : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rs     : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rt     : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rd     : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            shamt  : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            funct  : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
        end record;

        -- i type instructions
        type I_Type is record
            opcode    : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rs        : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            rt        : std_logic_vector(c_instr_bits - 1 downto 0);
            immediate : std_logic_vector(c_immed_bits - 1 downto 0); --can used as offset value
        end record;

        --j type instructions
        type J_Type is record
            opcode  : std_logic_vector(c_op_bits - 1 downto 0);
            address : std_logic_vector(c_address_bits - 1 downto 0);
        end record;


        --alu code definition
        type alu_code is (  c_alu_add, c_alu_addu, c_alu_sub, c_alu_subu,
                            c_alu_and, c_alu_or, c_alu_nor, c_alu_xor,
                            c_alu_sllv, c_alu_srlv, c_alu_sll, c_alu_srl,
                            c_alu_sra, c_alu_srav, c_alu_zero,
                            c_alu_error --needed?
                            );
        --when to branch 
        type branch_condition is (bc_beq, bc_bgtz, bc_blez, bc_bne);

        --how much data to load
        type load_mode is (ld_lb, ld_lbu, ld_lh, ld_lhu, ld_lw);

        --how much data to store
        type store_mode is (st_sb, st_sh, st_sw);

    end package Instructions_pack;

    package body Instructions_pack is
    end package body Instructions_pack;
```

hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

I use the following shared variable code to simulate a multi-port memory in one of my projects. In this case, the simulator's memory footprint is much smaller and simulation runs faster than using simple signals.

To my knowledge, this is not synthesizable and may not be supported by all simulators.

```
architecture behavioral of testbench is
    type shared_ram is protected
        procedure write(addr: in integer; value: in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0));
        impure function read(addr: integer) return std_logic_vector;
    end protected shared_ram;

    type shared_ram is protected body
        -- bit_vector has a smaller simulation memory requirement than std_logic_vector
        type ram_t is array(0 to 2**25-1) of bit_vector(63 downto 0);
        variable ram: ram_t;

        procedure write(addr: in integer; value: in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)) is
        begin
            ram(addr) := to_bitvector(value);
        end procedure write;

        impure function read(addr: integer) return std_logic_vector is
        begin
            return to_stdlogicvector(ram(addr));
        end function read;
    end protected body shared_ram;

    shared variable ram: shared_ram;
begin
    -- Processes can use ram.write(address, value) and ram.read(address)
end architecture behavioral;
```